# AWS CDK, Fargate Service and ECR Lifecycle policy of created image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

Having multiple different applications, I would like to use ECR Lifecycle policy to clear old images. However since all images are at same place, I can't just wipe out images based on count / date.

I'm aware CDK now pushes *all* images into one ECR repository ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67441218/4842985)). I don't want to overcomplicate my CDK deployment with additional step with creating and pushing Docker image separately.

Is there any way how to (either):

- create custom ECR repository and push image to it (without jumping around separate docker push)
- tag images way it's usable to ECR lifecycle policy

... both just when simply using `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`?

This is code for setting up one of my services:

```js
    const fargateService =
      new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
        this,
        "FargateService",
        {
          serviceName: `LeApp-${envId}`,
          cluster: cluster,
          // ...
          taskImageOptions: {
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset("../"),
            containerName: "leapp-container",
            family: "leapp",
            // ...
          },
          propagateTags: ecs.PropagatedTagSource.SERVICE,
        }
      );
```

Comment: For now, it really seems not possible without additional step with ECR repo and ECR deployment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2663 & https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12597